# An open convex set is the intersection of all half planes containing it

Tags: complex-analysis, convex-analysis

> Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{C}$ be an open set that is convex. Show that $\Omega=\bigcap H_i$, where $\Omega \subset H_i$ and $H_i = \{ z: Im(a_iz+b_i)>0, a_i,b_i \in \mathbb{C}\}$

It is pretty clear that $\Omega \subseteq \bigcap H_i$ by definition. But I am not sure how to show the converse. Any thought?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It suffices to show that for any $p \notin \Omega$, there is a half plane $H$ containing $\Omega$ but not $p$.  For convenience, translate so $p = 0$. Let $S$ be the set of $w$ with $|w| = 1$ such that the ray
$\{t w: t > 0\}$ intersects $\Omega$.  Show that $S$ and $-S = \{-w: w \in S\}$ are disjoint and open, and use the fact that the unit circle is connected...

Comment: To make the hint more clear: assume $p\in \bigcap H_i \setminus \Omega$. Then, there is a half plane $H \supseteq \Omega$ but $p\notin H$. A contradiction.

Comment: Thank you very much! But how do I show that $S$ and $-S$ are open?